# How do I query all events in a specific city with a specific date using Eventbrite Api?

Tags: javascript, api, eventbrite

Basically I am trying to query all events happening today and tomorrow in the current user's city using the eventBrite API. The language is Javascript.  I am confused as I can use a GET request to the URL below to query all events.

```
https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search?token=MYTOKEN
```

I am however confused as to how include the specific city of interest and the start date of the event in the query.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I haven’t used their API, but is this really not covered in their documentation?

Comment: Seems like you need to append the relevant query fields to the URL. For example: https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?location.address=Brooklyn&start_date.range_start=2018-07-02T12%3A00%3A00Z&start_date.range_end=2018-07-03T12%3A00%3A00Z&token=PSO3HP6FDWEAGIESCAM5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the location.address parameter. You can find it in the documentation here: https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/endpoints/events/#ebapi-get-events-search

For example: GET /v3/events/search/?location.address=CITY&token=MYTOKEN

**Note be sure you include the / after search.